# Como mostrar una imagen con ajax y webMethod en asp.net c#

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net, imagen

Hola comunidad estoy trabajando en asp.net c# y trato de mostrar una imagen en mi aplicación web. Desde mi webMethod envio la url y por medio de ajax trato de mostrar mi imagen pero solo se ve un cuadro roto como si no encontrara la url.

Aquí coloco el código de mi ajax espero me puedan ayudar de antemano gracias.

```js
   
    var persona = 1;
    var Sucursal = "";
    var id_Rol = 1;
    
    if (persona != 0) {
    

    var valores;
    var url_imagen;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "frmPersona.aspx/Personas",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: '{id_Persona:"' + persona + '",Sucursal:"' + Sucursal + '",id_Rol:"' + id_Rol + '"}',
        async: false,

        success: function(data) {
           
            if (data != '') {

                valores = data.d.split("-");
                valores = JSON.parse(valores[0]);
                url_imagen = valores[1];// Aqui obtengo la url de la imagen ../img/Completo.png
                
                $("#imgProceso").attr("src", url_imagen);//Aqui quiero mostrar la imagen pasandole el url 
             
             
            }
```

```html
 <div class= container>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <img id="imgProceso"  />
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: buenas, seguro que está referenciándolo bien? me refiero si es correcta la ruta,por probarlo directamente en el html esa ruta

Comment: Hola @rubenchus gracias he corregido la ruta y ya me mostró la imagen.